# Как проскроллить элемент в selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, discord

В Дискорде есть список участников с полосой прокрутки, когда мы ее опускаем вниз участники на странице обновляются.
Мне нужно парсить всех участников канала, Но у меня не получается скроллить этот элемент. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свой вопрос.
Я получал скроллбар и скроллил его таким образом на 1500 пикселей вниз.

Потом я обходил в цикле всех видимых участников сервера и если селениум не может найти его на странице, я скроллил список пользователей и искал участников заново по `data-list-item-id`:

```
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[@data-list-item-id="members-802881024991690792___{i}"]')

element_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + 1500", element_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на похожий вопрос уже был дан - **[ТУТ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)**.

Задача решается разными способами:

- Вызов JavaScriptExecutor
- Нажатие ctrl+end
- Использование Java Robot class

**[Примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)**

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал для вас рабочее решение, но оно достаточно костыльное.

**Import**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
```

**Code**

```
pathToWebdriver = ''
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathToWebdriver)

channelUrl = ''
driver.get(channelUrl)
time.sleep(5)


def getOnline():
    online = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="members-697179618699903006"]/div/h2/span')
    data = online[0].text
    data = data.split('—')
    return data[1]


def getOffline():
    while True:
        xpath = "//span[@class='roleColor-rz2vM0']"
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        rangeOfList = len(elements)
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()',
                              elements[rangeOfList - 1])

        offline = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="members-697179618699903006"]/div/h2/span')

        if offline != []:
            data = offline[0].text
            data = data.split('—')
            return data[1]


def main():
    users = []
    usersCount = int(getOnline()) + int(getOffline())
    while True:
        xpath = "//span[@class='roleColor-rz2vM0']"
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
        rangeOfList = len(elements)
        for element in elements:
            print(element.text)
            if element.text not in users:
                users.append(element.text)
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()',
                              elements[rangeOfList - 1])
        time.sleep(1)
        if len(users) == usersCount:
            break
    print(users)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Либо я не правильно что-то делаю, либо не знаю. Но не работает.
Я поставил задержку больше, чтобы успеть авторизоваться, открывается окно, я перехожу на нужный сервер и на 14 строке "data = online[0].text" выдает ошибку.
переменная online равна пустому списку.

Comment: Скину вам более универсальное решение позже

Comment: А что за элемент вы достаете в online?

Comment: количество человек онлайн

Comment: Это то что в h2 хранится?
<h2 class="membersGroup-v9BXpm container-2ax-kl" aria-label="В сети, 35 участников"><span aria-hidden="true">В сети—35</span></h2>
Нам тут просто число надо получить?
И кстати зачем?

Comment: чтобы получить всех участников, в канале